# Google Cast Receiver Applications

Tags: google-cast

In the receiver developer's guide is the following:

> Applications running on the Google Cast receiver device (receiver applications) are always web applications. They are launched on the device after it receives instructions from the sender application to do so.

How exactly is this accomplished from the sender (in Chrome)? The sender guide doesn't seem to include this anywhere and I'm unable to track down it down in the API docs.

There is the class cast.LaunchRequest, but there isn't anything there that would accept a receiver application URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a little hard to figure out at first. What happens is you have a sender and a receiver. For the sake of simplicity lets say we are making a chrome app. Chrome app is synonymous with a Web Page running on chrome.

So what we would have is two web apps (pages).

- Sender (Web Page)
- Receiver (Web Page)

You then get your sender [whitelisted](https://developers.google.com/cast/whitelisting#whitelist-chrome), by giving them the url to your web app's root. In a day or two they send you an Application ID. That application ID acts as your ActivityID (in the place of say 'Netflix' or 'YouTube').

When you say `cast.LaunchRequest("[AppId]", receiver);` from you sender. The receiver pulls down the web page that corresponds to that AppId, which uses the [Receiver Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/cast/developing_your_receiver) to talk to your sender(s).

The sender can also be on android or iOs in those cases you only have to make one Web App.

Comment: Actually, cast.LaunchRequest("[AppId]", content);  You can send a URL to the content, or some other info that your Receiver needs.  The AppID is all that's required to load your Receiver.